# How to use 2 canvas in the same function

Tags: javascript, canvas

There is a photo I want to cut it 2 times
so I made 2 canvas and I want them to
work but only the first one work but the second one doesn't cut the photo

```js
let skinin = document.getElementById("skin");
skinin.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);

function handleFiles (e) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
  canvas.width = 64
  canvas.height = 64
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const Skin = new Image;
  Skin.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  Skin.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(Skin, -8, -9, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                console.log(canvas.toDataURL())
                }
  let face = canvas.toDataURL()
  const FACE = new Image()
  FACE.src = face
  const canvasface = document.getElementById("canvasFACE"); 
  canvasface.width = 64
  canvasface.height = 64;
  const ctxface = canvasface.getContext('2d');
  ctxface.drawImage(FACE, 57, 57 , canvasface.width , canvasface.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasFACE"></canvas>
    <input type="file" id="skin" accept="image/*"/>
<img id="Pixelart"/>
<label for="skin" class="skinbtn"><div class="skintext">Upload Skin <i class="fa-solid fa-file-import"></i></div></label>
```

Comment: Can you edit the code snippet in your question to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Image isn't loaded yet when you run the code for the second canvas. Move it to the `onload` handler

Answer (score 1):

```
function handleFiles(e) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const canvasface = document.getElementById("canvasFACE");

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const ctxface = canvasface.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 64;
    canvas.height = 64;
    canvasface.width = 64;
    canvasface.height = 64;

    const Skin = new Image();
    Skin.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

    Skin.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(Skin, -8, -9, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());

        let face = canvas.toDataURL();
        const FACE = new Image();
        FACE.src = face;

        FACE.onload = function () {
            ctxface.drawImage(FACE, 57, 57, canvasface.width, canvasface.height);
            console.log(canvasface.toDataURL());
        };
    };
}
```